# How to get data, textStatus and jqXHR when calling await jquery.ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

I am using JQuery AJAX, using await. I do not want to use the success and error callbacks and I do not want to use the `.then` syntax.

When calling jquery ajax like so

```
const { data, textStatus, jqXHR } = await $.ajax(url, {...});
```

then the variables on the left are not populated.

How to call jquery ajax using await and still get `data`, `textStatus` and `jqXHR` (similar to the success callback)?

(Simply calling `const data = await $.ajax(url, {...});` works but I need access to `textStatus`and `jqXHR`.)

Comment: please don't forget to also upvote my answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the 3 parameters you specified in the `success` option for the `ajax` function and do the destructuring on that anonymous function

```
    let data, textStatus, jqXHR;
    await $.ajax(url, {success: (dt, txt, jqx) => {
      data = dt;
      textStatus = txt;
      jqXHR = jqx;
    }});
```

or extract the function and do it like this

```
...
const success = (dt, txt, jqx) => {
  data = dt;
  textStatus = txt;
  jqXHR = jqx;
}
...
await $.ajax(url, {success});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Based of the jQuery documentation (as i haven't used jQuery in many years), it seems that `$.ajax` returns `jqXHR` so one approach could be not to use await on the jqXHR object when you call `await $.ajax(...)` you could do something like the following instead

```
  const jqXHR = $.ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
  const data = await jqXHR;
  const statusText = jqXHR.statusText;

  console.log({ data, statusText, jqXHR });
```

or if you like it as a in your example you could write a small wrapper function, or maybe it is possible to achieve with the `$.ajaxSetup` as well

an example of a wrapper function could be something like

```
async function ajax() { 
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     $.ajax(...arguments)
      .then((data, statusText, jqXHR) => resolve({ data, statusText, jqXHR }))
 })
}
```

and you can then use `ajax` instead of `$.ajax` like

```
const { data, statusText, jqXHR } = await ajax("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
```